# GUI-enabled EmEditor alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notepad

I am an NLP research engineer and often work with huge (2-4Gb) text files. I need not only to look through them, but be able to perform searches, including regex-queries.

While using Windows OS there is EmEditor, which is totally awesome in working with huge files. Unfortunatelly they don't have a Linux version nor have a plan to make in the future.

I am looking for an alternative, which could be run natively under Ubuntu.

**Update.** I am looking for GUI-enabled app, console options won't do for me.

Comment: Sublime text or Atom

Comment: Probably should be moved to ask ubuntu and is duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-large-4-3-gb-plain-text-file/934794#934794

Comment: vim will open huge text files very fast. Search and every other function works without any issue.

Comment: @ChangQian Sublime is totally not for huge files. It runs too slow starting with 100Mb, I am not talking about gigabytes at all.

Comment: @ChangQian Tried out Atom -- it has issues with both huge files and non-latin non-UTF-8 encodings. Later is a critical one rendering it useless.